# Qual è il significato della frase "Ne va un po' di mezzo il vestito" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *L'isola*, di Giani Stuparich, ho letto:

> Il figlio trovò il padre seduto sulla riva. Badava a due lenze che aveva ai lati ed una la teneva in mano. L'aveva visto giungere da lontano e subito s'era rasserenato in volto.
>         – Da confonderti con un pescatore di mestiere, – esclamò il figlio. 
>         – Sì, alla brava. **Ne va un po' di mezzo il vestito.** Ci vorrebbe quella tela da marinai. E un berrettaccio con la visiera. Tu, t'annoieresti a star delle ore così?
>         – M'annoierei. A prenderlo il pesce, sì, ma ad aspettarlo...

Sapreste spiegarme il senso della frase "Ne va un po' di mezzo il vestito" che appare in questo testo? Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mezzo1) ho trovato

> *andar di m.*, patire danno, aver pregiudizio: *io non vorrei andarci di m.*; *figliuol caro, se tu ti senti il bruciore addosso, non so che dire*; *ma io non voglio andarne di mezzo* (Manzoni); *ne va di m. la vita, l’onore, la sua reputazione*; *mettere in m. qualcuno*, ingannare, raggirare, abbindolare, compromettere

ma quello che "va di mezzo" nel brano sopra citato è "il vestito" e non mi pare che il significato sia quello riportato dal dizionario.

Comment: La definizione della Treccani mi lascia perplesso; _andare_ (o _andarci_ ) _di mezzo_ significa nella mia esperienza "essere coinvolto"; In ogni caso non è questo il senso nella frase riportata. Nel caso indicato, secondo me la locuzione significa che il vestito c'entrava poco o nulla col mestiere di pescatore.

Comment: Attenzione, la definizione della Treccani è citata in modo poco chiaro: la parte sull'onore etc. si riferisce a quello che veniva prima (“_andar di m._, patire danno, aver pregiudizio”); mentre “ingannare...” si riferisce solo a “mettere in mezzo”.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG! Ho cercato di rimediare (si dice così?).

Comment: @Charo: Perfetto! E ci sei anche riuscita.

Answer (score 4):

Come riportato nell'estratto dalla Treccani, il senso generale della locuzione “andare di mezzo” è “subire un danno”. Si può riferire a persone (“qui ci vado di mezzo io”) o a cose, spesso astratte (l'onore, la reputazione etc. come negli esempi, ma anche la pelle). Scorrendo Google Books si trovano innumerevoli esempi sia antichi che moderni. Fra questi ultimi, forse qui più pertinenti:

> chi ci va di mezzo son sempre io (Vamba)
>
> loro la mettono in punizione e chi ci va di mezzo sono io che non posso uscire con lei (Moccia)
>
> Il giorno in cui l'Arno tracima e Ponte Vecchio rischia di crollare, ne va di mezzo anche la libreria (Carlo Feltrinelli)

Nel caso di cui parliamo, sono dell'opinione che il personaggio che parla osservi che il vestito che indossa è poco adatto, in particolare perché si potrebbe rovinare indossandolo mentre si pesca, a differenza di quelli fatti con la “tela da marinai”.

Comment: +1, un'interpretazione a cui io non avevo minimamente pensato ma che è certamente possibile. Faccio fatica a conciliarla con il commento sul cappello però.

Answer (score 3):

Il padre qui sta dicendo che il vestito che indossa non è proprio da pescatore (piuttosto "ci vorrebbe quella tela da marinai. E un berrettaccio con la visiera"). In questo caso il vestito "compromette" la somiglianza tra il padre e un marinaio. Da notare lo scambio immediatamente prima:

> – Da confonderti con un pescatore di mestiere, – esclamò il figlio.
>
> – Sì, alla brava. [Vale a dire "approssimativamente"]

Comment: Il contesto farebbe pensare qualcosa del genere, ma dal normale significato di “andare di mezzo” sembra anche che, vestito in quel modo, danneggia quello che indossa (mentre invece la tela è fatta apposta per essere più resistente).

Comment: @DaG Forse si tratta di un mio idioletto, ma per me "andare di mezzo" significa genericamente "intralciare", sia in senso letterale che figurato, che è perfettamente coerente con questa intepretazione (cfr "mettersi in mezzo").

Comment: Interessante. Non saprei, io direi più in questo secondo modo, “(ci) si mette in/di mezzo”.

Comment: Da una rapidissima ricerca con Google Books sulla stringa “va di mezzo”, sembra che si parli in genere di cose o persone che ricevono un danno (l'onore, la pelle...), “chi ci va di mezzo son sempre io” (Vamba) fino ai recenti “loro la mettono in punizione e chi ci va di mezzo sono io che non posso uscire con lei” (Moccia) e “Il giorno in cui l'Arno tracima e Ponte Vecchio rischia di crollare, ne va di mezzo anche la libreria” (Carlo Feltrinelli).

Comment: @DaG Sono d'accordo che la tua scelta sia più idiomatica (e ora che ci penso, conosco anche l'altro significato), ma questo tipo di sostituzione semantica ("andare" per "mettersi", quando entrambi indicano un movimento) non è del tutto inusuale. Ad ogni modo credo che possiamo essere tutti d'accordo che questo sia il significato del brano :).

Comment: Cioè che si sciupa il vestito? A me continua a suonare lievemente più così, devo ammettere.

Comment: Anzi, meglio che lo metta come risposta.